# Is there a Sami legend of a Shaman using human body parts to ward off demons?

Tags: myth-identification, sami

The second season of the television series [Fortitude](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498622/) revolves around a presumably Sami<sup>1</sup> legend of a murderous Shaman. The legend is described in episode 6:

> There's a legend among the people here that every few generations, the gods send down a plague to remind everyone of their power. And after the plague, a sort of demon rises up, the chosen one, and he can only be defeated by a powerful magic, and for that the Shaman needs certain body parts. And that's what I think is happening here - the husky, the heads, the heart. Someone is collecting body parts because they think there is a monster here.

Is this based on an actual Sami story or stories? And if yes, do we know where I can find a fuller version of it?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I'm assuming a Sami origin because the Sami people are mentioned numerous times in the show, and the location of the fictional settlement of Fortitude is in Arctic Norway.</sub>